# Python Pandas print column name if it match reference column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to print the column name in a new column 'result' if the 'b' or 'c' match (equal) 'a' for every row.

This is an example, I have more than 10 column names.

my df is like this:

```
   a   b   c
a  0   1   2
b  4   4   5
c  6   7   6
d  9   9  11
```

expected result:

```
   a   b   c   result
a  0   1   2      NaN 
b  4   4   5        b
c  6   7   6        c
d  9   9  11        b
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) on the comparison of `b`/`c` and `a` (with [`eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html)).

Also use a mask (with [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html)) to ensure there is at least one valid match as `idxmax` would return the first False index if no True is found:

```
m = df[['b', 'c']].eq(df['a'], axis=0)

df['result'] = m.idxmax(1).where(m.any(1))
```

output:

```
   a  b   c result
a  0  1   2    NaN
b  4  4   5      b
c  6  7   6      c
d  9  9  11      b
```

intermediate `m`:

```
       b      c
a  False  False
b   True  False
c  False   True
d   True  False
```